# Problema UITableView cuando no recupera datos de BD

Tags: swift2, swift, xcode

Hola que tal tengo un problema, soy muy nuevo en swift, hice un UITableview sacado de una base de datos mysql, cuando el webservices me trae datos no hay problema, es decir la tabla se me carga con los datos correspondientes, pero cuando el web services trae vacio me sale un error. El codigo me que da error es el siguiente:

```
func parseJSON() {

    var jsonResult: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()


    do{
        jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSMutableArray

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)

    }

    var jsonElement: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    let locations: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    for i in 0..<jsonResult.count
    {

        jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

        let location = ComunicadosLocationModel()


        if let mensaje = jsonElement["mensaje"] as? String,
            let fecha = jsonElement["fechapublicacion"] as? String,
                let estado = jsonElement["estado"] as? String

            {
                location.mensaje = mensaje
                location.fechapublicacion = fecha
                location.estado = estado

        }

        locations.addObject(location)

    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

        self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(locations)

    })
}
```

La linea que me marca el error es

```
jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSMutableArray
```

Que podría ser?

Comment: ¿Podrías subir el `JSON` que estás intentado parsear?

Answer (score 0):

Te da error porque `self.data` es nulo

Para que no de error y falle la app, deberias hacer esto:

```
if self.data != nil {
    jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSMutableArray
}
```

Haber si te funciona

Answer (score 0):

Como menciona *@user9099*, el problema está en `self.data`.

Al ejecutarse:

```
do{
    jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSMutableArray

} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)

}
```

Se intenta insertar en `jsonResult` un objeto `JSONObject`, pero si hay un error, entonces, se ejecuta lo que haya dentro del `catch`. Viene vacío `self.data = nil`, y por tanto no se puede crear el objeto `JSONObject`.